# What does 'being' mean at the first of a sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

My question is what does 'being' mean at the first of a sentence?

Here are some examples.

> Being rich doesn't mean you are happy.

What does being rich mean?

> Being a successful person in life is a big challenge.

What does being successful mean?

> Being a doctor doesn't mean you are smart.

What does being a doctor mean?

I appreciate your effort and I am looking forward to the answer.

Comment: FWIW, I think *Being a successful person in life is a big challenge*, though possible, sounds odd. *Becoming a successful person in life is a big challenge* would be better, and *Becoming a successful person is a big challenge* or *Becoming successful in life is a big challenge* would be the best, IMHO.

Comment: It might help if you imagine a "deleted" subject *(**You** being rich doesn't mean you are happy)*. But strictly speaking, I think ***being*** in such contexts is a "gerund" (verb acting as noun), so it's structurally the same as *I enjoy cycling*, or *Hang-gliding is dangerous*.

Comment: @Damkerng: I have to say I don't think there's anything in the least "odd" about the version you're not keen on. And changing *being* to *becoming* could significantly affect the meaning - consider, for example, *Being a woman in Yemen isn't very satisfying if one can see how **other** people live.* To be honest, it wouldn't surprise me to discover that the authorities in Yemen don't even *permit* anyone to "become" a woman (by surgical/hormonal treatment).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understand your comment. Still, I think it sounds odd, or at least ambiguous. I think the ambiguity would become more obvious with a simpler sentence such as *Being a senator is not easy.*

Comment: @Damkerng: You have the edge on me, since I don't really understand *your* comment. To my mind, *Being president isn't easy* is a reference to what it's like *if you are president* - it implies nothing about any possible difficulties involved in *becoming president*, just as *Becoming president isn't easy* implies nothing about how things will be if you do actually achieve that ambition.

Answer (score 1):

1. Being rich doesn't mean you are happy.
2. Being a successful person in life is a big challenge.
3. Being a doctor doesn't mean you are smart.

The sense of "being" at the start of a sentence depends on its context.

In all the sentences being has been used as a gerund. Being rich, being a doctor, and being a successful person are gerund clauses that are subjects of the sentences.

These sentences imply as follows:

1. If/when you are  rich, it doesn't mean you are happy.
2. If/when you are a doctor, it doesn't mean you are smart.
3. It is a big challenge to be a successful person in life.

You can also use to-infinitive instead of being, but the use of the to-infinitive isn't so common.

Besides, in the construct of some sentences, being is also used to express a reason or cause as an alternative to because, since, or as.  For example:

Being the youngest, Sara is her father's favourite.

Comment: I think the last usage you mentioned is not limited to verb "to be". ex: studying hard, I passed the exam.